# laravel непростой запрос в бд

Tags: php, веб-программирование, laravel

Всем привет. Есть таблица `post` в котором поле `id , user , content , image`. В поле `user` имеется  id пользователя. Можно ли как то одним запросом получить в ответ такую примерно структуру:

```
[{
   id: 1,
   user: 2,
   username: Fariz,
   userimage: img.jpg,
   content: text,
   image: 1.jpg,
}]
```

Думаю показывать таблицу `user` не обязательно. Не судите строго если вопрос не очень

Comment: Можно конечно, для этого надо определить связи между таблицами.

Comment: @u_mulder а как это реализовать? если есть пример или экзампл буду признателен

Comment: https://laravel.ru/docs/v5/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 2):

Ответ оказался очень прост. Определить отношения один к одному в модели `Post`:

```
public function user(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\User' , "phone" , "user");
}
```

и дальше запрос в бд:

```
// with("method user")->where("column user" , "id") 
Post::with("user")->where("user" , "62891947")->get()
```

Спасибо u_mulder что направил куда смотреть